# drawing over drawn graphics in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

hi I am trying to implement a form which resizes using coding. I have use the form_paint method to paint a border but I cannot "paint over" this border. What i am intending to do is that as i resize the form using a timer for a "smooth resizing", the form border would be updated along with the resize. what should i do?

```
    Pen setupControlPen = new Pen(SystemColors.Control, 16);
    Pen setupDimGrayPen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, 5);
```

inside my form_paint: //draws a form border

```
    Rectangle newRectangle;
    newRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));
    setupGraphics.DrawRectangle(setupDimGrayPen, newRectangle);
```

inside a click event: //i tried to draw over the already drawn border.

```
    Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));
    setupGraphics.DrawRectangle(setupControlPen, newRectangle);
```

thank you!

update: I tried using both resize_form event and timer to redraw but still cannot re-draw the border whenever i resize the form.

update 2: the override method works! regarding the setupGraphics:

```
    //global space
    Graphics setupGraphics;

    //form_load
    setupGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

    //so whenever I want to draw something during an event, supposing a button click event to draw a line:
    setupGraphics.DrawLine(pen, point1, point2);
```

I would like to ask are there any flaws in this method? or should everything be done inside the form_paint method?

Comment: Is your FormBorderStyle set to None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding the `OnPaintBackground` method and set the style of the form to ResizeRedraw and double buffer it:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
}

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Control);

  using (Pen setupDimGrayPen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, 5)) {
    Rectangle newRectangle;
    newRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(setupDimGrayPen, newRectangle);
  }
}
```

It's not very clear where `setupGraphics` is coming from in your post.

Comment: Not sure you should be encouraging creating objects inside a paint event. Pen is best done outside and disposed of correctly with the class. I would argue the DrawRectange overload that takes x, y, width and height is better too... I did upvote you though

Comment: hi using the protected override method works without setting the style and it works even with doublebuffered set to false. I have since edited my question with the setupGraphics.

Comment: @user776914 The Graphics object is best used from the Paint events.  If you need to draw something different based on a button_click, setup a local variable to determine "which" pen you want to draw with.  Call Invalidate() on the form if not resizing the form in the button click event to refresh the graphics.

Answer (score 4):

Painting for container controls is optimized.  That gets in the way in your case, you want the Paint event to fire when the form size changes.  Make your constructor look like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

Or do the border drawing in an override for OnPaintBackground().

Answer (score 2):

So does your click event actually resize the form? If no change is made to the form then the form will not try to repaint, you could try one of these...

```
form.Invalidate();
form.Refresh();
paintControl.Invalidate();
paintControl.Refresh();
```

paintControl is for if you have a control other than form that the paint is actually being done on, you should only refresh the smallest control/area required

Also, dont forget to set DoubleBuffered to true for your form/control

**EDIT:** I am not sure what setupGraphics is? Why do you not use the e.Graphics object on the Paint event args?

Comment: oh i declared it as : Graphics setupGraphics; in global space. in form_load event I intialize it as setupGraphics = this.createGraphics();

Comment: @user776914: sounds like it could be a contributing factor. Try using the e.Graphics or the OnPaintBackground as suggested elsewhere... the other answer look good